# ImportError: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python

I tried below code and getting the ImportError: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I am using
cuda-10.0
torch-1.4.0
mmdet-1.2.0

```
import mmcv
from mmdet.apis import init_detector, inference_detector, show_result_pyplot
```

Here I am providing the complete traceback of the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-fd733e93e63e> in <module>
      1 import mmcv
----> 2 from mmdet.apis import init_detector, inference_detector, show_result_pyplot
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/apis/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .inference import (async_inference_detector, inference_detector,
      2                         init_detector, show_result, show_result_pyplot)
      3 from .test import multi_gpu_test, single_gpu_test
      4 from .train import get_root_logger, set_random_seed, train_detector
      5 
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/apis/inference.py in <module>
      9 from mmcv.runner import load_checkpoint
     10 
---> 11 from mmdet.core import get_classes
     12 from mmdet.datasets.pipelines import Compose
     13 from mmdet.models import build_detector
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/core/__init__.py in <module>
      5 from .mask import *  # noqa: F401, F403
      6 from .optimizer import *  # noqa: F401, F403
----> 7 from .post_processing import *  # noqa: F401, F403
      8 from .utils import *  # noqa: F401, F403
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/core/post_processing/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .bbox_nms import multiclass_nms
      2 from .merge_augs import (merge_aug_bboxes, merge_aug_masks,
      3                          merge_aug_proposals, merge_aug_scores)
      4 
      5 __all__ = [
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/core/post_processing/bbox_nms.py in <module>
      1 import torch
      2 
----> 3 from mmdet.ops.nms import nms_wrapper
      4 
      5 
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from .context_block import ContextBlock
----> 2 from .conv import build_conv_layer
      3 from .conv_module import ConvModule
      4 from .conv_ws import ConvWS2d, conv_ws_2d
      5 from .dcn import (DeformConv, DeformConvPack, DeformRoIPooling,
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/conv.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from .conv_ws import ConvWS2d
----> 4 from .dcn import DeformConvPack, ModulatedDeformConvPack
      5 
      6 conv_cfg = {
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/dcn/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .deform_conv import (DeformConv, DeformConvPack, ModulatedDeformConv,
      2                           ModulatedDeformConvPack, deform_conv,
      3                           modulated_deform_conv)
      4 from .deform_pool import (DeformRoIPooling, DeformRoIPoolingPack,
      5                           ModulatedDeformRoIPoolingPack, deform_roi_pooling)
/table/CascadeTabNet/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/dcn/deform_conv.py in <module>
      9 
     10 from mmdet.utils import print_log
---> 11 from . import deform_conv_cuda
     12 
     13 
ImportError: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: _Do_ you have that library installed on your system?

Comment: (and if you have it, is it the same version? If you have a different version of libcudart.so, then you might want to recompile the relevant Python module to be linked against the one you actually have).

Comment: ...insofar as libcudart is a C library, the typical way to install it is using your distro's package manager. That might be `apt-get`, `yum`, or something else along those lines, as appropriate for whichever OS you're running.

Comment: CUDA 10.0 and CUDA 10.1 are not the same thing. You have CUDA 10.0 installed. You need CUDA 10.1

Answer (score 1):

There is a compatability issue with your Pytorch/CUDA version and the required detectron2 Pytorch/CUDA version.

First figure out what CUDA version you can using

```
nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.45.01    Driver Version: 455.45.01    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    On   | 00000000:07:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     9W /  N/A |    393MiB /  7973MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I have CUDA Version 11.1, with that go to the installation page [here](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html) and go to the table with the CUDA versions and run the coommand, for me it was

```
python -m pip install detectron2 -f \
  https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu111/torch1.8/index.html
```

Comment: Be carefull, because the CUDA version returned by nvidia-smi command is not the installed but the maximum version supported by the installed driver. You can check the installed version (almost the active one) using "nvcc -V"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

You can know that by entering the following:

```
$ nvcc --version

Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try reinstalll you pytorch with cuda version 10.1, then rebuilt the mmdetection.

i did it and it is solved.

the problem may be you cuda related with pytorch and cuda with mmcv(or mmdet) are not compatible.

tips: cuda version from "nvcc -V" and "nvidia-smi" are different, i misunderstand them at first.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the proper version of cuda:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```